# How to skip BIRT read a cell, read a row message when downloading pdf report on Tomcat console

Tags: tomcat, birt

Using Apache Tomcat Version 8.0.26 and BIRT Runtime 4.5.0
When I download a pdf version of the report from BIRT Viewer my Tomcat console window is getting a message like below:-
Read a row…
Read a cell…

The larger the number iof pages in Pdf the more number of these message and hence they fill up the Tomcat console screen everytime I download a Pdf report.
Is it possible to prohibit this message from printing on the Tomcat console window?

[image]

Comment: what you have tried yet?How you coded for generating pdf?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These messages are written in class:

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.emitter.PageDeviceRender
```

See method "startContainer":

```
protected void startContainer( IContainerArea container )
    {
        ...

        if ( container instanceof RowArea )
        {
            System.out.println("read a row...");
            rowStyleStack.push( container.getBoxStyle( ) );
        }
        else if ( container instanceof CellArea )
        {
            System.out.println("read a cell...");
            drawCell( (CellArea) container );
        }
        ...
```

A quick fix would be to comment these two messages, compile the resulting class and replace the older ".class" file in birt runtime.

Comment: Hi Dominique, Thanks a ton. I tried to look for the file in location C:\Tomcat\webapps\birt\WEB-INF\lib but cannot locate the JAR. DO you know where can I locate the file in BIRT runtime?

Comment: Found the Jar containing the class file.It is org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.5.0.jar in the same location.

Comment: @AjayBhandari, I downloaded the entire source code for birt, but I do not see the org.eclipse.birt.runtime_4.5.0.jar.  Could you please check on a package name and the path inside that package?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the game on this answer. I was having the exact same issue with BIRT v4.5. I reverted back to v4.4.2 without issue and the messages never came back. It's not ideal by any means, but if you are not using features specific to v4.5, it may be an option for now, until an update is released (looks like v4.6 RC4 is available).